# Modern SharePoint: How to create a form that is hosted on the site (instead of personal cloud account)?

Tags: forms, sharepoint-online

When I embed '**Microsoft Forms**' web parts on pages on my department's **SharePoint Online (Teams site)** to collect custom feedback the Excel response file gets saved in my individual OneDrive account. It's still a business account, not a personal account, but it's not shared by anyone else. So if I'm not there to share the results, the other site owners will not have access to the results. *(To clarify, this is NOT for SharePoint sites created for Teams in MSTeams.)*

Need a way for results to be accessible to all site owners, please. Research online so far, only shows how to embed the form web part. (I haven't yet tested if another site owner can edit the form. If they can't, that is another issue I'll need to address).

Answer (score 0):

Embedding the form into a SharePoint site **will not move** the form into the Teams group. You would have to explicitly move the form has to be moved from your personal account to your Teams group instead.

1. Click on the 3 horizontal dots "..." of your forms.

[image]

2. Choose the Teams / Internal group to move the form into.

[image]

3. Submit a form response and the Excel spreadsheet should appear within your SharePoint site contents.

Comment: Thank you. So then I should create an MS Teams' 'Team' for that? I can't move it to the SharePoint Online site? I tried to copy and paste but although the form has a 'copy' option, no 'paste' option shows in document library on the SharePoint Online site. Just want to confirm this is not doable before requesting a Teams site.